# ARKit – Session's configuration check

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

How would I check for the currently running tracking configuration?

```
if sceneview.session.configuration == ARWorldTrakingConfiguration() { 
    print("foo") 
}
```

Doesn’t do the job. I understand that I am comparing some types, so the statement is never true. But is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

All `ARSession` configurations are subclasses of `ARConfiguration` so you can  check if your current configuration is of the appropriate type like below:

```
if sceneView.session.configuration is ARWorldTrackingConfiguration {
    print("configuration is of type ARWorldTrakingConfiguration")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your *if-statement* inside `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter()` to give an extra time (0.5 second) for your configuration to be initialised and run.

Here's a code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {

        if self.sceneView.session.configuration == ARWorldTrackingConfiguration() {
            print("Current configuration is a WorldTracking")
        } else {
            print("Current configuration isn't known")
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S. Remember, it doesn't work on iOS Simulator and on Playground**.